# Unable to write to Manifest file in maven build

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, manifest.mf

I am trying to get info recorded to the manifest-file, but I dont get anything except below in my manifest file after the build

Manifest-Version: 3

Specification-Title: 3

This is my build task in pom, where i tried giving manifest entries true, but in vain :(

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>deployJarToRepositoryBasedOnVersion</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                      <addDefaultImplementationEntries/><addDefaultSpecificationEntries/>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <artifactId>${component-name}</artifactId>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <repositoryId>${jfrog.repository.id}</repositoryId>
                <url>${jfrog.repository.url}</url>
                <file>${project.build.directory}/classes/${component-name}.jar</file>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: maybe you miss <manifestEntries> wrap around your keys

Comment: wrap keys into <manifestEntries> tag and place inside archive after manifest. should be ok

Comment: That doesn't work, have already tried it.

Comment: Yeah I see, this is not only issue

Comment: this one should be ok if you set all your parameters correct. I can not check it , no active deploy projects at hand

Comment: by the time you calling maven-deploy-plugin your jar-file is already built. That is why no changes in your manifest file. Check updated answer. GL :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
   <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries/><addDefaultSpecificationEntries/>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <artifactId>${component-name}</artifactId>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <repositoryId>${jfrog.repository.id}</repositoryId>
                        <url>${jfrog.repository.url}</url>
                        <file>${project.build.directory}/classes/${component-name}.jar</file>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deployJarToRepositoryBasedOnVersion</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>${jfrog.repository.url}</url>
                        <file>${project.build.directory}/classes/${component-name}.jar</file>
                        <repositoryId>remote-repository</repositoryId>
                        <artifactId>${component-name}</artifactId>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```